# How to convert CET time to local time on device?

Tags: java, android, time

I have three different times:

time on server - "**Wed, 19 Feb 2014 11:44 CET**"

time of start meeting on server - "**12:00h**"

time on device- "**13:49**"

I need to get time of start meeting on device ...this-> "**14:00h**" or time to meeting this-> "**11m**"

I'm trying to get it by using :

```
                    long ts = System.currentTimeMillis();
                    Date localTime = new Date(ts);
                    String gmt_time="12:00h"; 
                    SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm'h'");
                    format.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
                    Date d_date = null;

                        d_date = format.parse(gmt_time);

                    format.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));



                     Date fromGmt = new Date(d_date.getTime() + TimeZone.getDefault().getOffset(localTime.getTime()));
                     String new_date=format.format(fromGmt);
```

But result in new_date is **"15:00h"** (I need "**14:00h**")

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You assumption of `CET` = `GMT` on `Wed, 19 Feb 2014` seems to be incorrect - refer to [here](http://wwp.greenwichmeantime.in/to/cet/).

CET is an hour ahead of GMT

11:44 CET would mean 10:44 GMT

Hence, when you calculate an offset from GMT time and your local time, it adds an hour to it.

Change `format.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));` to `format.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("CET"));` and it should work as expected.

Comment: Thanks for fast answer

Answer (score 0):

Found quickly solution

```
              String cet_time="12.11.14"+" "+"12:00h"; 
            SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yy' 'HH:mm'h'");
                    format.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("CET"));

                    Date d_date = format.parse(cet_time);

( new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yy")).format(fromGmt);//new date String
( new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm'h'")).format(fromGmt);//new time String
```